# SELECT rows matching an aggregate function without using a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM products)` selects all products with a above-average prices.

Is it possible to do this using aggregate functions somehow instead of a subquery (nested `SELECT`) or a Common Table Expression (`WITH`).

I am asking primarily about Postgres but MySQL or SQL Server also helps.

Something like `SELECT * FROM products HAVING price > AVG(price)`, which doesn't work.

Comment: please state database engine expound your problem

Comment: As you see from the posted answers, it seems that the answer is no. Can you tell us now why not use a subquery or derived table or...?

Comment: The main reason was a case where there are many such sub selects for the same table within a query and I wondered if there was a syntactically better way when it becomes more complicated. Looks like no

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.

And there is one additional line because the answer must be at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve these using inner join.
Check below query.

```
SELECT p1.* FROM products P1
inner join (SELECT AVG(price)as price FROM products) P2 on P1.price > P2.price
```

Answer (score 0):

The derived table for this solution is only syntactic sugar to be able to apply a `where` condition on the column alias:

```
select *
from (
  select p.*, 
         avg(price) over() as avg_price
  from products
) t
where price > avg_price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the average result in a variable and use that variable in the main query or wherever it is required.

```
DECLARE @avgPrice DECIMAL(5,2);
SET @avgPrice = (SELECT AVG(price) FROM products);
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > @avgPrice;
```